# ggplot: adding a label to a geom_line aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a for loop plotting 3 `geom_line`s, how do I add a label/legend so they won't all be 3 indiscernible black lines?

```
methods.list <- list(rwf,snaive,meanf)
cv.list <- lapply(methods.list, function(method) {
  taylor%>% tsCV(forecastfunction = method, h=48)
})
gg <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x))
for (i in seq(1,3)){
  gg <- gg + geom_line(aes_string( y=sqrt(colMeans(cv.list[[i]]^2, na.rm=TRUE))))
}
gg + guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Forecast"))
```

If I don't use a loop, I can use `aes` instead of that horrible `aes_string` and then everything works, but I have to write the same code 3 times and replace the loop with this:

```
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=sqrt(colMeans(cv.list[[1]]^2, na.rm=TRUE)), colour=names(cv.list)[1]))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=sqrt(colMeans(cv.list[[2]]^2, na.rm=TRUE)), colour=names(cv.list)[2]))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(y=sqrt(colMeans(cv.list[[3]]^2, na.rm=TRUE)), colour=names(cv.list)[3]))
```

and then there are nice automatic colors and legend. What am I missing? Why is r being so noob-unfriendly?

Answer (score 0):

The example is not reproducible, (there is no data!) but it seems you have some information in a list `cv.list` which contains multiple data.frames, and you want to plot some summary statistic of each against a common varaible stored in `x`.

The simplest method is simply to create a `data.frame` and plot using the data.frame.

```
#Create 3 data.frames with data (forecast?)
df <- lapply(1:3, function(group){
    summ_stat <- sqrt(colMeans(cv.list[[i]]^2, na.rm=TRUE))
    group <- group
    data.frame(summ_stat, group, x = x)
})
#bind the data.frames into a single data.frame
df <- do.call(rbind, df)
#Create the plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = summ_stat, colour = group)) + 
       geom_line() +
       labs(colour = "Forecast")
```

Note the change of label in the `labs` argument. This is changing the label of `colour` which is part of `aes`.

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work - it creates a single line... :( editing the question for reproducibility